# Не могу нормально передать в функцию параметр

Tags: javascript, html5, css-animation

Не могу понять в чем проблема. при выводе в консоли console.log(box) - вроде норм, отображает весь список. как задаю ему console.log(box[number]) - undefined;

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    var boxRight = document.querySelectorAll('.box-right');
    var bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i].onmouseover = function (){
           showGrey(i);
        }
        box[i].onmouseout = function (){
            hiddenGrey(i);
        }
        bar[i].onclick = function(){
            alert('Удаленно');
        }
    }
    function showGrey(number){
        console.log(box);
            boxRight[number].classList.add('cl-box2');
            bar[number].classList.add('cl-bar2');
    }
    function hiddenGrey(number){
            boxRight[number].classList.remove('cl-box2');
            bar[number].classList.remove('cl-bar2');
    }    
}
```

```css
.box-left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
}

.fa-times {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  margin: 23px;
  color: #fff;
}

.box-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}

.fa-check {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.bar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cl-bar2 {
  width: 80px;
}

.cl-box2 {
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
      <div type='button' name='delete' class='box' >
        <div class='box-left'>
          <i class='but-icon fa fa-lg fa-times'></i>

          <div class='bar'>
            <i class='but-icon fa fa-lg fa-check'></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-right'></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете в обработчик функцию без параметров, которая *во время выполнения* вызывает другую функцию, которая в качестве параметра получает значение переменной **i**. Так как переменная **i** одна, обработчики событий всех элементов будут обращаться только к одной единственной переменной, значение которой определяется и меняется в процессе выполнения цикла. В данном случае, так как в цикле срабатывает операция инкремента (увеличение на единицу) в конце ей присваивается значение 1, поэтому все обработчики будут обращаться к этой единственной переменной со значением 1, а элемента boxRight[1] не существует, поэтому возникает ошибка.

Есть два варианта решения этой проблемы.

1) Использовать встроенный метод функций **bind**, который жестко устанавливает this (в данном случае не нужен) и аргументы.

```
box[i].onmouseover = showGrey.bind(null, i)
box[i].onmouseout = hiddenGrey.bind(null, i);
```

2) Использовать современные возможности JavaScript: в цикле переменную **i** вместо var объявляйте с помощью директивы **let**. Однако старые браузеры не поддерживают ES6. В такие случаях используют Babel, который переписывает код на предыдущий стандарт ES5.

```
for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  // код...
}
```

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    var boxRight = document.querySelectorAll('.box-right');
    var bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
    for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i].onmouseover = function (){
           showGrey(i);
        }
        box[i].onmouseout = function (){
            hiddenGrey(i);
        }
        bar[i].onclick = function(){
            alert('Удаленно');
        }
    }
    function showGrey(number){
            boxRight[number].classList.add('cl-box2');
            bar[number].classList.add('cl-bar2');
    }
    function hiddenGrey(number){
            boxRight[number].classList.remove('cl-box2');
            bar[number].classList.remove('cl-bar2');
    }
```

```css
.box-left {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
}

.fa-times {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  margin: 23px;
  color: #fff;
}

.box-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top-right-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
}

.fa-check {
  font-size: 70px !important;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

.bar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cl-bar2 {
  width: 80px;
}

.cl-box2 {
  left: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div type='button' name='delete' class='box' >
        <div class='box-left'>
          <i class='but-icon fa fa-lg fa-times'></i>

          <div class='bar'>
            <i class='but-icon fa fa-lg fa-check'></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box-right'></div>
        </div>
```